# Highly Imbalanced dataset

Tags: python, land-classification, machine-learning

I have a dataset (vector data) that contains the polygons and their corresponding crop type. This data is highly imbalanced i.e, I have a lot of classes that contain one sample only, as shown in the photo down below. To oversee this issue I tried to implement SMOTE but this throws an error because SMOTE needs at least 2 samples of the same class to create new ones (k_neighbors=1 by default).

I can't just use the dataset as it is because the results are going to be biased towards large classes and (2) some algorithms throw an error during training.

[image: imbalanced dataset]

What I don't understand is that the minority class (correspond to one polygon in the vector data) would cover more than one pixel (when matched with the features, I have 15 features) therefore, at least 15 pixels correspond to one of the minority classes.
This the error I get:

```
ValueError: Expected n_neighbors <= n_samples,  but n_samples = 1, n_neighbors = 2
```

Is there a way to overcome this issue? Should I duplicate the existing samples and then use SMOTE to oversample them?

Comment: In my opinion, this question should be asked at https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I have already posted it there. I want to see how one can approach this from a data scientist's point of view and from a geoscientist or someone experienced with GIS point of view.

Comment: Cross-posted as https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/476926/66276